# Pulling Calcium Phosphate from Animal Bones

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, chemical-biology

I am looking to pull Calcium Phosphate out of animal bones (chicken, fish, etc) without destroying the collagen. If I soak animal bones in brown rice vinegar will the vinegar pull out Calcium Phosphate leaving behind the collagen 'bendy bone'? Or is it just pulling out Calcium?

Comment: Chances are it will. Why won't you try it? Chemistry is an experimental science, after all.